# Retrieve table names from views using PL/SQL script

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, view

I'm looking to find the source tables used by the views in my DB. I need a fully automated solution. For example I have a view that pulls data from another view which pulls data from table. It's easy enough to browse the DDL script of each view and drill down to find the table but I'm looking to write a script to do it for me across all views. Should I go against the data dictionary? does anybody have tips or a script or query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: so if i  understood it correctly you want to have a recursive list of tables used in the particular view and all its potential subviews - is this correct?

Comment: I would expect that you could walk through `dba_dependencies` to get this assuming you don't care whether a table is listed because it's referenced as a join or in an inline query inside a view or referenced by a function that is called by a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only what the tables, recursively referenced, try this.  The 'CONNECT BY' clause does the recursive drilling for you:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  sys.dba_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_type = 'TABLE'
START WITH "NAME" = 'VIEW_NAME_IN_QUESTION'
CONNECT BY PRIOR REFERENCED_NAME = "NAME" AND "TYPE" = 'VIEW';
```

Drop the where clause if you want to see all object types.  The REFERENCED_NAME column gives you your list.